# Function to export workspace objects(data frames) to csv files

Tags: function, r, export-to-csv

I want to batch export data frames in my workspace having the string "obj" in their names to a csv file with the same name

I thought of the following code, which unfortunately does not work.

```
for (i in ls(pattern="obj")){
write.csv2(i, paste(i,".csv", sep=""))
}
```

Any ideas? Thank you in advance

Comment: Just guessing, but if you've got a bunch of things named after some pattern, such as obj1, obj2, etc then you'd be much better off storing them in a list. Then you just loop over the list rather than constructing names and using 'get'...

Comment: You're right. Will do. Thanx!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`write.csv2` takes the object rather than the name of the object as its first argument.  Use `get` to remedy this.

```
write.csv2(get(i), paste(i,".csv", sep=""))
```

Comment: To clarify,  try these two lines:  write.csv2(x,file='foo.csv')  and write.csv2("x",file='bar.csv') .   The second version is not what you want, but it's what your original code was doing.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with `eval`:

```
eval(call("write.csv2", as.name(i), paste(i, ".csv", sep="")))
```

Comment: Very fancy, but when you come back to the code in six months, will you remember what it does?  See `library(fortunes); fortune("eval")`.